# Making my item unbreakable in my 1.12.2 Minecraft mod

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a set of armor and tools that I've made unbreakable. I found two solutions so far: the obvious one, giving the item millions for a durability value; and the second, setting the durability as 0 or a negative to make it infinite. The prior works just fine, and only makes it so you can see the durability bar, which I don't like, but while the latter makes the item unbreakable, it can't be enchanted. Any ideas? here's my init registration code for these.

```
public static final ToolMaterial TOOL_MATERIAL_COLORITE = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("tool_material_colorite", 3, 0, 24.0F, 26.0F, 100);
public static final ToolMaterial DAGGER_MATERIAL_COLORITE = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("dagger_material_colorite", 3, 0, 24.0F, 16.0F, 100);
public static final ArmorMaterial ARMOR_MATERIAL_COLORITE = EnumHelper.addArmorMaterial("armor_material_colorite", Reference.MOD_ID + ":colorite", 0, new int[] {24, 48, 64, 24}, 100, SoundEvents.ITEM_ARMOR_EQUIP_DIAMOND, 0.0F);
```

Thanks in advance.
Edit: I haven't changed anything, but now for some reason the helmet and chestplate are unbreakable and unenchantable, while the boots and leggings still take damage and are enchantable. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't helpful to me. I'm trying to make a mod, and this post is about making a vanilla minecraft map. I do know about the existance of the "unbreakable" NBT Tag, but I don't know how to add it to my tools and armor. if you have another post that focuses on that instead, or if you know where I can learn to add an NBT tag upon crafting or something similar, that would be great. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution, but it's a(unoptimized) way to make armor unbreakable.
Basically, you need to make an onArmorTick method and enter this:

```
@Override
public void onArmorTick(World world, EntityPlayer player, ItemStack itemStack) 
{
    setDamage(player.inventory.armorItemInSlot(3), 0);
    setDamage(player.inventory.armorItemInSlot(2), 0);
    setDamage(player.inventory.armorItemInSlot(1), 0);
    setDamage(player.inventory.armorItemInSlot(0), 0);
}
```

Slot 3 is the helmet, 2 is the chestplate, 1 is leggings, and 0 is boots.